# All citations become undefined when I add an image

Tags: biblatex, graphics, bibliographies

I am using Latex to write the documentation for my dissertation project but when I go to add in an image (this isn't the first image I have put into the document) and recompile, Latex throws errors telling me that all of my citations within the document are undefined. I narrowed it down to this specific image that is causing the document to fail to compile, but I can't understand why it is doing this as it has been fine with all of my other images. the code I am using to add the image into the document is below:

```
\subsubsection{Small 15x15 Cell Maze}
This small 15x15 cell maze is the first of the three new mazes which will be implemented in this project to evaluate the effectiveness of the new human-like maze solving algorithm. Again, this is a simply connected maze meaning that it can be solved using the Hand on the Wall technique.


\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.5]{images/Small15x15.png}
    \caption{Image of a small randomly generated maze found at www.mazegenerator.net \citep{mazeGen}}
    \label{fig:15x15Maze}
\end{figure}

\subsubsection{Medium 25x25 Cell Maze}
This medium 25x25 cell maze is the second of the three new mazes. It was generated using a maze generating and solving program Daedalus v3.3. This maze presents a more complicated structure than the previous as it is larger and is a multiply-connected maze much like the Chevening House maze. Figure \ref{fig:25x25Maze}  shows the 2D representation of the maze.

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.5]{images/new25x25maze.png}
    \caption{Image of the medium 25x25 cell maze. Generated using Daedalus v3.3}
    \label{fig:25x25Maze}
\end{figure}
```

The last image that I add is what makes the document fail to compile and causes my citations not to load. but if I remove the image the document compiles.
If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ANSWER: After playing around in the document for a while, I found that the image did not convert from bitmap to a PNG correctly so after exporting the image as a PNG once more and then adding it into the document solved this problem.

Comment: You should accept your own answer (unless some better one shows up) to close this issue.